Privacy implications of using OAuth 2 in local Microsoft apps
When setting up OAuth authentication in Microsoft applications, I'm prompted with scary dialogs like the ones below.  This example is using Outlook 2016 to configure a GMail account[1], but I've seen similar screens in other apps.
"Microsoft apps & services" is ambiguous and the prompt doesn't make it clear whether the access and information described will be shared with Microsoft, or just the local application I'm using.
I'm not deeply familiar with OAuth but I gather it involves tokens, challenges and responses bouncing back and forth across the cloud.  Does this digital chatter take place solely between the software on my machine and Google's servers?  Or does Microsoft's implementation rely on some of their cloud infrastructure to support the sign-in process?
i.e. Does using this form of authentication 'ping' Microsoft in a way that could leak to them the fact that I'm signing in?

I understand how 'legacy' passwords work.  You set up credentials in the software and it presents them to the server when you want to authenticate.
My mental model of OAuth isn't as clear, and I want to understand the privacy implications as the line between 'local' and 'cloud' becomes more blurred.
[1]Starting in Fall 2024, GMail is disabling access to apps that don't use OAuth (such as older IMAP clients which log in using a traditional username and password).  So you'll no longer have the choice to do it the old fashioned way, and I can see more services following suit.

This has nothing to do with technology. It's similar to the change that Microsoft made when they switched to modern authentication. You receive a longer lived token from a server to use for authentication rather than authenticating with the application server directly. If you have questions about privacy, contact the vendor .

Those are standard dialogs to perform OAUTH authentication with your Google account. Microsoft or anyone that uses OAUTH is not provided with your Google account password only a confirmation you were successful in authenticating your account

You can see what OAuth exchanges by generating an authentication for rclone

@Ramhound is Microsoft provided that confirmation, or just the Outlook  software on my local machine?  I want to know if MS has any involvement in the authentication process.  Put another way: If MS went bankrupt tomorrow and all their servers went down, could I still set up a new GMail account in Outlook 2016?

One more note regarding the bounty - documenting use of a packet sniffer (like WireShark) to verify no information is exchanged with non-Google servers during the account setup process, and when subsequently logging in, could also qualify as an authoritative reference.

Sniffing won't help - OAuth 2.0 safety is a matter of the implementation of the client application and of the OAuth service. Both, if having the smallest flaw, can leak the access token whose implication is to give the attacker complete access. The question becomes this: Are you sure that the Microsoft implementation is absolutely attack-proof? And how can this be proven?

Thanks @harrymc.  I just want to understand whether there is any information flow to Microsoft in the normal course of account setup and logon.

The information given by the client is his client id and one secret identification. The ideas are the same as since decades ago, just the implementation is more robust. The risk with a token-using algorithm is the stealing of the tokens via Phishing, Fake authentication pages, Counterfeit resource servers, Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF), Open Redirection, Authorization Code Interception, Flawed Scope Validation, Token Reuse, Insecure Client Implementation, Poor Authorization Server Configuration. Risk mitigation methods are regular user education and multi-factor authentication.

Not too sure what's the purpose of this question. What is this trying to avoid? Even if you Wireshark or w/e requests for OAuth and they ping or don't ping Microsoft, the app could ping their servers on many other occassions. What are the positives of knowing it only for OAuth process?

@Destroy666 - I want to know if it pings Microsoft any 'more' under OAuth than it does when using regular passwords.  I don't think it's unreasonable to want to know if Microsoft is involved in the sign-in process (or 'sign-in registration') between me and non-Microsoft parties.

Some important things to consider :
(1) OAUTH 2 is safer than a password.

OAuth 2.0 is an authorization protocol and NOT an authentication
protocol. As such, it is designed primarily as a means of granting
access to a set of resources, for example ... user data.

An app which knows your password and username, has unrestricted access to your account. In the case of Gmail, this means that a rogue app could take complete control of your account and of all connected Google services, such as Drive, Calendar, YouTube account, Android phones, developer APIs and so on.
With OAUTH instead, the app will tell the Google server what data it wants to access, and Google prompts you as user to confirm, showing exactly what data the app will have access to. And you have the possibility to review such data request (that's the "scary dialogue" you mention).
Once you confirm, the server issues a revokable OAUTH Access Token (or rather, an Authorization code which the app can exchange for an Access token - for details, read the first link).

OAuth 2.0 uses Access Tokens. An Access Token is a piece of data that
represents the authorization to access resources on behalf of the
end-user.

This means that you as user can at any moment revoke the access you previously granted to an app, as described here. So, you don't need to change your password just because for some reason you don't trust an app anymore. On the other hand, even if you change your password, the OAUTH access will remain valid (so you don't have to re-enter your password in multiple connected apps !)
(2) Does using this form of authentication 'ping' Microsoft in a way that could leak to them the fact that I'm signing in?
Possibly yes, but that's anyway the case, independently of OAUTH. Microsoft can know every time you open Outlook, since they made that app. And if you use that app, they will "know" your Gmail address, since you have to enter it so that Outlook can send emails on your behalf. Microsoft can know every single keystroke you make in Outlook. How much data they collect is written in their privacy policy and can be up to a certain extent controlled through settings in Outlook. After that, it's a question of how much you trust Microsoft.
(3) Which Data will OAUTH add to this?
The usual implementation is that the app itself connects to Google's OAUTH server, and your app will store any secret locally, on your computer. As you can read in the first link OAUTH establishes a direct link between the client and the authorization server:

Using OAuth 2.0, access requests are initiated by the Client, e.g., a
mobile app, website, smart TV app, desktop application, etc.

Microsoft might redirect this through a server of their own, but given the considerations §2, this is totally irrelevant.
(4) the prompt doesn't make it clear whether the access and information described will be shared with Microsoft, or just the local application I'm using
As described in §2, this amounts to the same thing. Outlook is controlled by Microsoft, so potentially they have access to anything you do within this app. It amounts to how much you "trust" Microsoft not to read your personal email. Given that Microsoft is currently pushing CoPilot and other AI applications, they might wish to send all your data to their server, so they can "help" you write emails "better and faster", using "your trusted AI Copilot". So be sure to read the privacy policy, and configure the privacy settings in Outlook. And keep being wary of product updates: never click through agreements.
(5) So, can I trust Microsoft ?
The Article you have linked yourself, is not about Outlook 2016, but about the "New Outlook", but there it is written:

When adding a mail account in the new Outlook that is not hosted by
Microsoft but is located on company mail servers, for example, the
program displays a message. It links to a support article that simply
states that non-Microsoft accounts are synchronized with the Microsoft
cloud, whereby Gmail, Yahoo, iCloud and IMAP accounts are currently
supported. The new Outlook also does this in the versions for Android,
iOS and Mac. This means that copies "of your email, calendar, and
contacts will be synchronized between your email provider and
Microsoft data center". This gives the company full access to all
emails and allows it to read and analyze them.

This makes the direction Microsoft is going very clear, and such practice might in the future just "swap over" with an automatic product update. So, make your own choice.
What I would recommend is to use an open-source mail client run by a Non-Profit, like Mozilla's Firefox. It might take some time to adapt, but your data will stay only with Google, and not go to Microsoft (if that's any better for you). So, what I would really recommend is to use some non-free but privacy aware email service.
